# Get objects where lowercase/no-space name is equal to lowercase/no-space parameter in Django filter

Tags: python, regex, django, filter

I would like to get all `products` where no-space/lowercase version of `name` field is equal to no-space/lowercase version of `input_product_name` parameter in Django. How can I do this?

**Pseudo-code**

```
def get_or_add_product(input_product_name):
    return Product.objects.filter(where no-space/lowercase version of name == input_product_name.strip().lower())
```

Comment: I know I can lower/strip `input_product_name` with `.lower().strip()`, but how do I apply this to the model `name` field?

Comment: In SQL form: `'WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) = {}'.format(input_product_name.strip().lower()) `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Django's queryset [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and [expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions) with its [Database Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions).

For example, in your case:

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Lower, Replace


def get_product(input_product_name):
    input_product_name = input_product_name.lower().replace(' ', '')

    return Product.objects.annotate(
        lowered_nospace_name=Lower(Replace('name', Value(' '), Value('')))
    ).filter(
        lowered_nospace_name=input_product_name
    )
```

Note that SQL's `Trim()` and Python's `strip()` only strip the blank spaces at the beginning and the end of your string. For example, `strip('  hello  ') == 'hello'`.

***Security Note***

Writing raw SQL can help in your case, however, please use it only as the last resort if you can't express your query using Django QuerySet methods. [The Django team will deprecate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra) the `extra()` function in the future since it can open to [SQL Injection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) attacks.

Answer (score 2):

```py
## In-case spaces are to removed from beginning and end only
Product.objects.extra(
    where=["LOWER(TRIM(name)) = %s"],
    params=[input_product_name.strip().lower()]
)
## In-case spaces are to removed from everywhere in string
Product.objects.extra(
    where=["LOWER(REPLACE(name,' ','')) = %s"],
    params=[input_product_name.strip().lower()]
)
```

[reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: I made a typo in my example. `upper` should be `lower`

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't return 'iPhone X' when `input_product_name` = 'iphonex'?

Comment: I think I found the reason why: I need to use `replace` instead of `trim`

Comment: hmm, my edit returns: `Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok got it, I forgot to escape the quotes

Comment: @dunkubok you ask from TRIM then suggest answer with REPLACE why ? you want space to be removed from everywhere in the string ?

Comment: I just realised `strip()` only strips the blank spaces at the beginning and the end of your string, thanks to @Luan. That's not what I wanted...

Comment: In your reference link, the Django team advised against using `extra()` as it can lead to SQL injection attack. The `extra()` function will be deprecated soon as well.